# guide me in decoding this object please?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm a have a php code that call the facebook api me/home and fetch me this result. But the problem is don't know how to decode it. So I want to ask for help here.

```
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#276 (9) {
["id"]=>
string(31) "100000000155611_312548192088517"
["from"]=>
object(stdClass)#275 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) "Jun Revistual"
  ["id"]=>
  string(15) "100000000155611"
}
["message"]=>
string(95) "lifes interesting...  if you stay alive, good things are bound to happen. :))
One Piece Movie 4"
["actions"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#274 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Comment"
    ["link"]=>
    string(61) "http://www.facebook.com/100000000155611/posts/312548192088517"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#273 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Like"
    ["link"]=>
    string(61) "http://www.facebook.com/100000000155611/posts/312548192088517"
  }
}
["type"]=>
string(6) "status"
["created_time"]=>
string(24) "2011-11-17T05:18:17+0000"
["updated_time"]=>
string(24) "2011-11-17T05:19:31+0000"
["likes"]=>
object(stdClass)#272 (2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#271 (2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Andrei Natividad"
      ["id"]=>
      string(9) "614714754"
    }
  }
  ["count"]=>
  int(1)
}
["comments"]=>
object(stdClass)#269 (2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#258 (4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(39) "100000000155611_312548192088517_4977358"
      ["from"]=>
      object(stdClass)#267 (2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Andrei Natividad"
        ["id"]=>
        string(9) "614714754"
      }
      ["message"]=>
      string(17) "what's the title?"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2011-11-17T05:18:45+0000"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#260 (5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(39) "100000000155611_312548192088517_4977363"
      ["from"]=>
      object(stdClass)#266 (2) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "Jun Revistual"
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "100000000155611"
      }
      ["message"]=>
      string(37) "One Piece Movie 4: Dead End Adventure"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2011-11-17T05:19:31+0000"
      ["likes"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["count"]=>
  int(2)
}
}
```

up to now I'm still just here:

```
foreach($wall as $value) {
echo "<pre>";
echo $value[0]->id;
print_r($value);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

dont even know if this is right.

Comment: That looks like its already decoded... What are you referring to by decoding?

Comment: i believe you are already doing right, the data has been decoded from json and u are accessing it in right way.

Comment: i edited my sample for more clarification. What I want is to get the name of the poster which is Jun Revistual and his message which is "lifes interesting...  if you...". then those people commented in his post. I want to structure it like in my facebook home page.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code:

```
$data = $facebook_object_response;

    echo $data->data[0]->id;
```

if it's an object you could access the data by "->" if it's Array access it like this "`[<index>]`".

Comment: done that working and added a for loop to it then it displayed a result but at the last part this throws me an error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /my_app.php on line 59

Comment: try to add an if condition on your loop to identify if it's still accessing an object or not